# Space complexity of classification algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, decision-trees

There is a categorical dataset consisting of n instances, m attributes. We are performing categorical clustering into K clusters. What is the [space complexity](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22229/space-complexity) for the following classifiers:

1. Decision Tree classifier
2. Support Vector Machine classifier
3. Artificial neural network with one hidden layer consisting of 2/3rd neurons of input data
4. KNN classifier?

Answer (score 2):

1. Decistion Tree: $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for constant depth (you might have bad accuracy, though)
2. SVM: $\mathcal{O}(K)$ if you use a linear kernel and one-vs-all
3. ANN: I don't know what "2/3rd neurons of input data" means
4. KNN: $\mathcal{O}(n)$ - you have to store all $n$ samples.